# USAID Dataset Downloads Published List

Tags: data-request, metadata, usaidopen

My understanding is that you are collecting data on the frequency of downloads of every dataset uploaded to the DDL (Development Data Library). Have you uploaded that dataset of downloads?

I am interested in knowing the number of downloads of every USAID dataset pertaining to health - funded by the Bureau for Global Health as well as by every USAID mission with a health program.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for the inquiry. The DDL is USAID's Development Data Library located at [www.usaid.gov/data](http://www.usaid.gov/data).  We do collect basic web traffic statistics and will start looking into this with our CIO's office to kick off the process of posting download  statistics on a regular basis.

As of November 30, 2015, these stats are now posted [here](https://www.usaid.gov/data/dataset/8f6d860a-f16f-448a-b06e-24ac6364e555).